# Using Spritebatch with varying rotation origin

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm drawing a tile-based game. Some tiles can rotate, about their centre. It appears that setting a rotation origin for one SpriteBatch.Draw call effects all other Draw calls with no origin specified.

Is there a way to avoid having to speficy the origin for every other draw call for non-rotating tiles?

Ideally i don't want to have to batch drawing my non-rotating tiles together and draw before/seperately to my rotating tiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It appears that setting a rotation origin for one SpriteBatch.Draw call effects all other Draw calls with no origin specified.

This is simply not the case. The `origin` for `Draw` applies only to that particular `Draw`.

If you are using an overload of `Draw` that does not specify an origin, an origin of `Vector2.Zero` is implicitly used.

Now, if you are actually passing a matrix to `Begin`, that matrix will be applied to *all* `Draw` calls (including ones where you set an origin) on that particular sprite batch until its `End` method is called.

You should use the rotation parameter of `Draw` to rotate individual sprites in your world. You should use the matrix parameter on `Begin` to move the view of all of your sprites around (like a camera).